# Python/C API - The result is not displayed

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-c-api

I would like to integrate C modules in the Python, so my choice fell on the interface `Python.h`. Everything compiled without errors and warnings, so I can not understand what the problem is.

C side:

```c
#include <python3.5m/Python.h>
...
#define PyInt_AsLong(x) (PyLong_AsLong((x)))
typedef PyObject* Py;

static Py getSumma(Py self, Py args){
  Py nums;
  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &nums)){
    return NULL;
  }
  size_t numsAmount = PyList_Size(args);
  int32_t summa = 0;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < numsAmount; i++){
    Py temp = PyList_GetItem(nums, i);
    int32_t num = PyInt_AsLong(temp);
    summa += num;
  }
  return Py_BuildValue("l", summa);
}

static PyMethodDef moduleMethods[] = {
  {"getSumma", (PyCFunction)getSumma, METH_VARARGS, NULL},
  {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static PyModuleDef SummaLogic = {
  PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
  "SummaLogic",
  "",
  -1,
  moduleMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_SummaLogic(void){
  return PyModule_Create(&SummaLogic);
}
```

setup.py:

```python
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

SummaLogic = Extension("SummaLogic", sources=['SummaLogic.c'])
setup(ext_modules=[SummaLogic])
```

Python side:

```
from SummaLogic import getSumma

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = getSumma(a)
    print(b)
```

It seems right, but when I start it in terminal - nothing happens, just hanging without any activity. What could I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to [`PyList_Size`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/list.html#c.PyList_Size) and that you don't check for errors there.

You probably wanted to use it on `nums`, not `args` as argument. However you used on `args` and a very interesting thing happened:

- `args` is a `tuple`,
- therefore `PyList_Size` failed and returned [`-1`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/403ccddb9598bac6e0e6db4ba5aa2fe494512a98/Objects/listobject.c#L190)
- that `-1` which was cast to an unsigned `size_t` which probably resulted in a very huge number, probably `2**64-1`
- therefore your iteration runs a "very long time" because it takes quite a while to iterate over `2**64-1` items (apart from all the out-of-bound memory accesses).

The quick fix would be to use:

```c
Py_ssize_t listlength = PyList_Size(nums);  /* nums instead of args */
if (listlength == -1) {  /* check for errors */
    return NULL;
}
size_t numsAmount = (size_t)listlength /* cast to size_t only after you checked for errors */
```

However you should check what the error conditions are and test for them after every python C API function call otherwise you'll get a lot of undefined behaviours. Also I probably would stick to the defined return types instead of `int32_t` (`PyInt_AsLong` returns `long` so you might get weird casting errors there as well!), `size_t`, ... and the `typedef PyObject* Py;` makes things really tricky for someone who regularly writes C extensions.

Comment: Very grateful! You saved me a lot of time)

Comment: @errfrom You're welcome :) I actually got a segmentation fault when running your script so it was quite easy to debug using gdb.